# SSH Key issues on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am moving from Google Cloud to AWS EC2. Issue I am experiencing is that I am unable to modify SSH keys in any shape or form.
This hinders testing a lot, since any bad key will cause me to redo the key assignation to the instance, etc etc.

I created the keypair directly from AWS (.pem), cannot connect through SSH (Catalina) `Permission denied (publickey).`

Same when I import the to AWS from my computer. AWS accepts them ok, but then SSH refuses to work.

When I was setting up Google Cloud, I had to match the comment of the public key to the username of the account. Is there anything else like that in EC2?

Comment: What OS are you connecting to?  Are you sure the username is correct?  Can you connect with SSM Agent?

Comment: Hey @AnonCoward! Thanks for your reply. I've explored the SSM Agent (kinda complicated, but maybe 'cos I'm a n00b), and I ran into the SSH client settings. Surprisingly, the username for my AWS account seems to not be the one to login, as EC2 recommended the following string: `ssh -i "key_name.pem" admin@public_dns_instead_of_ip` and it worked! Now, where the heck do I get `admin`from? I never saw such username.

Comment: The default account names [are documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/connection-prereqs.html), different AMIs have different default usernames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out connect via Systems Manager service(SSM) and you can connect to your instance via the browser [Connect to Linux Instance via SSM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/session-manager.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Stefanos! I replied about my findings on the comment above.

Comment: @mariano-daniel when you connect via SSM you will have admin privileges, see [Setting up Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-getting-started.html)